# How to provide a test datasource in spring?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, junit

I'm studying Spring with Hibernate now. I have a POJO model class annotated with Hibernate annotations called Person, PersonDao interface and it's hibernate implementation and a PersonService class. I'm using annotations so they aren't defined as beans in my spring-config.xml. Now I want to write some JUnit4 tests for my PersonService class, but I want to use different database while testing. Here is my spring-config.xml

```
<context:component-scan base-package="org.example" />
<tx:annotation-driven />

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/example" />
    <property name="username" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="pwd" />
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>
            ...
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

And I want in my tests the jdbc:mysql://localhost/example_test database to be used. How do I achieve that?

Comment: Your unit tests should not use a database as their not supposed to test the database but your class instead, try something like mockito instead http://code.google.com/p/mockito/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Move `jdbc:mysql://localhost/example` to configuration file (`db.properties`)

  database.uri=jdbc:mysql://localhost/example
- Put this file somewhere in classpath (i.e. `src/main/resources`)
- Set up property placeholder and use database URI property key in Spring context

  ```
  <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:db.properties" />
  ...
  <property name="url" value="${database.uri}" />
  ```
- Create configuration file with the same name in test classpath (`src/test/resources`)
- Change database URI property to test value (`jdbc:mysql://localhost/example_test`)

  database.uri=jdbc:mysql://localhost/example_test

Profit

Answer (score 1):

Extract definition of `dataSource` into separate XML file and provide different versions of that file when creating application contexts for test and production (i.e., `spring-config.xml` and `datasource-prod.xml` for production and `spring-config.xml` and `datasource-test.xml` for test).

Alternatively, you can use [profiles](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.0.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-definition-profiles) to distinguish between test and production environments while using the same set of config files for both.

Yet another approach is to keep common definition of `dataSource` but externalize its properties into property files. But it won't allow you to use completely different definitions for different environments (for example, connection pool in production and simple `DriverManagerDataSource` for tests).

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like that and specify another spring-context with another datasource, session factory, etc...

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {
    "/spring-context-test.xml",
})
public class MyTestClass extends AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests
{

}
```